# Элемент содержит 2 других элемента. Как расположить один из них центрально?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

Не могу найти решения похожей проблемы. Есть 3 элемента, контейнер, содержащий 2 других элемента, изображение и диалоговое окно. Изображение должно располагаться слева, а диалог быть посередине контейнера, перед изображением. Пока что получилось добиться подобного эффекта применив к Dialog элементу top и left свойства, но этот метод работает некорректно и меня интересует, можно ли решить проблему используя flexbox или grid.

Вот так располагаются элементы:

```html
<Paper>
    <img />
    <Dialog>
        Some content
    </Dialog>
</Paper>
```

В итоге должно выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диалоговое окно можно центрировать как обычно при помощи flex/grid:

```css
Paper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

А самой картинке задать абсолютно позиционирование в пределах родителя:

```css
Paper > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1; /* Чтобы картинка была позади диалогового окна */
}
```

А ещё можно задать картинку через `background-image`, и это буде правильно, если по смыслу картинка фоновая.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!